# How to exclude _id property from MongoDB Atlas query with NodeJS Express application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I cannot omit my _id field when I go to retrieve my documents from a MongoDB Atlas collection.

```
    const cursor = await client.db("databaseName").collection("collectionName").find();
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in the `find()` is the project list.

The catch here is that whenever you project data, _id is never removed by default. To remove _id you need explicitly exclude it like this:

```
    const cursor = await client.db("databaseName").collection("collectionName").find({name: ""}, {_id: 0});
```

-> find() documentation reference [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

-> projection details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#std-label-method-find-projection)

Answer (score -1):

This ended up working for me.

```
    const cursor = await client.db("databaseName").collection("collectionName").find({},{ projection: { _id: 0}});
```

Comment: $project aggregation stage is absolutely valid with NodeJS. It does not depend on the driver, it is a stage that is processed by the MongoDB instance. Hence there is inaccuracy in the answer.

Comment: @GobindDeepSingh thank you bhaee, I will look a bit more into my syntax. I think calling .find( {} , { _id: 0 } } ) was what I used initially. I will try .find( {<field>:" "} , {_id: 0 } ) next time I make a db call. My above code does work though. I will edit my answer to remove the comment about $project not working